# My confusion about the usage of double quotes in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Recently, I am busy coding the bash script to feed my needs. However, during the coding time, I found the usage of double quotes is contradicted with each other at some times. For example, I try to find some files that matched the regex, such as `ls "*.log"`. I habitually wrap the `*.log` with double quotes but get the error `cannot access '*.txt': No such file or directory`.

After that, I found the reason from a tutorial that it is useless to put the `*` in double-quotes when you want the `*` acts as a wildcard. Therefore, `ls *.log` is the correct usage.

However, when I use the `grep` command with regex, all three of them (`""`,`''`,non-quote) do not change the original meaning of my regex, such as `grep "^s.txt"`. At this time, double-quotes make the regex active.

Is there exist some design conflicts between the commands? And could you please give me some tricks to quickly grasp the correct usage of quotes for usual commands?

Comment: _"`Is there exist some design conflicts between the commands?`"_ yes, of course; these are completely two different commands and having different functionalities. see `man grep` and `man ls` for more info.

Comment: Shells such as `bash` use globbing to represent multiple filenames using special characters called wildcards with a single filename. A wildcard is essentially a symbol which may be used to substitute for one or more characters.  `bash` also supports extended globbing; The options extglob and globstar must be set to get the extended functionality, i.e. `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: @αғsнιη, I mean..I think  `grep` and `ls` are all builtin bash commands at the very beginning, so they shouldn't conflict the rule of bash that how to handle and parse the double-quotes. However, now I found grep is not the builtin command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `ls *.log` it's the shell who [expands the wildcard](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) before `ls` is started. Then `ls` is given the *result*. The tool has no functionality to expand `*` by itself.

In case of `grep "^s.txt"` the shell only removes the quotes (which are still useful in general to tell *the shell* how to treat the quoted string), `grep` gets `^s.txt` and does its job. In case of unquoted `^s.txt` the shell has nothing to do, so the result is the same. But it could be different in general (e.g. with `a*.*txt`).

Compare this: [`find` and globbing (and wildcards)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429309/108618). Both the `find -name` and the shell are capable of using `*` as a wildcard. It depends on the quoting which one will act. The results are usually different, sometimes erroneous. You need to know whether you want the shell to expand `*` or not.